# LeakCanary not installed in launcher

Tags: leakcanary

I did the change as suggested in app:build.gradle ->
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'

But when i pushed my apk, then i cannot see the Leak Canary in my launcher
Nay idea why?

Answer (score 0):

@Harsh,
Did you implement an app with multiple buidtypes?

***If yes*** you need to change the LeakCanary dependency follow your build types:
Example:
your build type is

```
buildTypes {
dev{}
....
release{}
}
```

if you want to install with the dev variant, your dependency should be like this: ***dev***Implementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:xxx_xxx'

***If not:*** remove this line in build gradle

```
variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
        setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```